# c++ char* parsing

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, char

SO, I am trying to write a function that will return a `vector<char**>`, as such:

```
vector<char**> test(string mystr) {

  char*temp=new char[mystr.size()+1];

  strcpy(temp,mystr.c_str());

  char*subStr=strtok(temp,":");

  while(subStr!=NULL) {

    int i=0;

    char**args=new char*[200];

    char*tempsta=newchar[strlen(subStr)+1];

    strcpy(tempsta, subStr);

    args[i]=strtok(tempsta," ");

    while(args[i]!=NULL) {

      i++;

      args[i]=strtok(NULL," ");

    }

    fullVec.push_back(args);

    //cout<<subStr<<endl;

    subStr=strtok(NULL,":");

  }
return fullVec;
}
```

so I want to `split` the parameter string up with `":"` delimeter, then with " " delimeter. On the `cout<<subStr` call I get what is expected if I comment out everything from `int i=0` to `fullVec.push_back(args)`. If I do not comment out all of those lines I only get the first `substring` (until the first ":") is encountered, and then the largest while loop exits.

for what is expected I mean; let us assume the parameter is "my name is: bon jovi: xxx ab"
if everything is commented out, the following lines will be printed:

```
my name is
 bon jovi
 xxx ab
```

if I leave it as is, what will happen is only

```
my name is
```

will print, and the large loop will exit

any assistance is appreciated, thanks! (Yes, I am aware that this seems like a silly exercise which can be done much more elegantly/easily...however I would like to get this solution to work before I entertain using string etc.)

Comment: Mixing C and C++ makes obnoxious bad code

Comment: You don't free *any* of your `new`d memory...

Comment: As long as you are writing C++ code, just avoid writing C-style code as much as possible. If you don't have a really good reason to use `char*`, then just use `std::string` instead.

Comment: -nneonneo you are correct, just trying to figure out this problem before continuing

--LiHo, I understand your point, but I won't be able to learn by just using conventional methods all the time without trying to 'explore'

Comment: @Dax Using `string` **is** the conventional method for C++. Also, "I know x and y are wrong but I want to fix z first" is the wrong approach in this case.

Comment: @DaxDurax: Fair enough you want to learn. But you should learn C and C++ separately. They are two different languages. Mixing them like this just leads to confusing hard to read code. I would re-write as a C solution and a different C++ solution. As the two techniques are completely different.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Very well written indeed, I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @DaxDurax: PS. Why did you remove all the white space it is really hard to read as it is. White space is your friend use it to make the code readable.

Comment: I don't think that your name is _really_ Bon Jovi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that strtok() maintains state between calls.

If the first parameter is not NULL then it uses to reset the state otherwise it uses the state it has saved to continue parsing from where it left off.

Since you have two nested calls to strtok() the second call is messing with state of the outer call.

This call:

```
args[i]=strtok(tempsta," ");
```

Is resetting the internal state of strtok(). It now no longer knows anything about the state from your outer call. Thus when you get to the end of the string in your inner loop.

This call:

```
subStr=strtok(NULL,":");
```

Is now using the saved state of the inner loop. So it basically just terminates as you have already reached the end of that tokenizing stream.

Comment: I guess this makes sense in some convoluted way....do you have any recommendations on getting around this while keeping the enclosed loop structure? Every solution I have seen online recommends seperating the loops

Comment: More bluntly, `strtok` modifies your C-style string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That is definately a thing to watch for (and one of the bad things about strtok()). But not the cause of any problems here.

Comment: @DaxDurax: No. If you are using strtok() you need to separate the loops. You can use `strtok_r()` which allows you to use a separate context for each tokenizing stream.

Comment: thanks loki strtok_r is exactly what I was looking for. The responses here are all very informative I just have to take them all in now!

Answer (score 2):

As it was perfectly pointed out by [Loki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14065/loki-astari) already, you should not mix C and C++. In case you want C++ solution for your problem, then it's better to stick with STL classes that will take care of ugly memory management for you (see [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) such as `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::istringstream`.

This is how your function could look like:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> Line;

std::vector<Line> parse(std::string inputString)
{
    std::vector<Line> lines;
    std::istringstream inputStream(inputString);
    for (std::string line; std::getline(inputStream, line, ':'); )
    {
        if (!line.empty())
        {
            lines.push_back(Line());
            std::istringstream lineStream(line);
            for (std::string word; std::getline(lineStream, word, ' '); )
            {
                if (!word.empty())
                    lines.back().push_back(word);
            }
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
std::vector<Line> lines = parse("my name is: bon jovi: xxx ab");

for (int li = 0; li < lines.size(); ++li)
{
    for (int wi = 0; wi < lines[li].size(); ++wi)
        std::cout << lines[li][wi] << "_";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

outputs

```
my_name_is_
bon_jovi_
xxx_ab_
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you are mixing C-style and C++-style code which results in quite a mess. Unless you have "good reason" to resort to `char*`  instead of `std::string` then it's better practice to make use of the `stl` or `boost`.

The `boost`way:

```
std::string delims = " :";
boost::split(vector, mystr, boost::is_any_of(delims));
```

The `stl` way:

```
  vector<string> result;
  std::string delims = " :";
  std::istringstream ss( mystr );
  while (!ss.eof())
  {
    getline( ss, field, delims);
    if ((empties == split::no_empties) && field.empty()) continue;
    result.push_back( field );
  }
```

For more approaches and a good comparison, see this [cplusplus article](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/)

Comment: There's no mention in the question of restricting boost use, and I added a stl alternative as well

Comment: "however I would like to get this solution to work `before I entertain using string etc`" :)

Comment: i'm just given my POV . i didn't down vote you because of this.But it may prevent others from upvoting you. :)

Comment: I suspect its an edit that was added after I started writing my answer but I might've missed it.

Comment: I stand corrected. My solution is less relevant to this question

Comment: This: `while(!ss.eof())` is a bad idea and anti-pattern (in all languages). The result of the read operation should be the value used in the test. `while(std::getline(ss, field, delims))`.